# How to set tomcat springboot project upload file path?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, war

I have a springboot project. Use WAR package, on the remote tomcat server webapps directory. ROOT is the WAR project, which has two folders, WEB-INF and META-INF.As shown below

[image]
[image]

Now there is a problem, I upload files on the project root directory 'upload-dir' directory (you can see the upload-dir position in the figure below). Not in the WAR package, and not on the remote server. Where should I create this new directory on the remote server?

[image]

[image]

I use **Files.createDirectories** to to create folders.

Comment: you need absolute path for upload dir, try change it to `c:/tmp/upload-dir` and see if it works at all.

Comment: There is no problem running the project locally. And 'upload-dir' is in the project's root path.  do not need an absolute path.

Comment: because your server knows nothing about your `project root path`

Comment: I have a try, thank you

Answer (score 0):

For this you can create a folder path   say `/home/upload_dir`.

Now upload the files through your app to this folder using absolute path in app. Create a `CONTEXT PATH` for this upload dir path in `server.xml` file as shown below.

```
<Context 
  docBase="/home/upload_dir" 
  path="/uploads" 
  reloadable="true" 
/>
```

I assume you are uploading some images to this folder. Now you can show images in your application by using the **url** Eg: `localhost:8080/uploads/imageName`

For prodcution you can create HOST with some sub domain in server.xml and access the uploaded file with the specified URL `(For eg: img.facebook.com/image)`

Comment: Maybe I can't describe the problem clearly, and your method has a deviation from my problem. But my problem has been solved. Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

On the Linux server, this folder is under the /root directory.

My English is not good. When I talk about my questions, I may not say it well enough. But I hope I can help other people who have the same problems.